# Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer ($2\times 2$ matrix)

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

[image]

I got the following solution by doing: $P^{-1}\times M^n\times P$ but it is not correct. 
I spent hours trying to solve this and find help online but I am out of options. Please help :(
Note:
eigenvalues of $4$, $4$;
egeinvectors of $(-1,4)$ $\&$ $(0,0)$.

Another similar problem here:

[image]

For some strange reason $a_{21}$ (lower left entry) was correct but the rest weren't. I kept rechecking my work but I could not figure out why.

Note: eigenvalues of $2$, $5$; egeinvectors of $(-2,1)$ $\&$ $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

An idea and hints: try to diagonalize your matrices, for example:

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}\;8&\;6\\\!\!-3&\!\!-1\end{pmatrix}\implies \det(xI-M)=(x-5)(x-2)$$

so the eigenvalues of this matrix are $\,2,5\,$ , and the corresponding eigenvectors are

$$\binom{\;2}{\!\!-1}\;,\;\;\binom{\;1}{\!\!-1}\implies P=\begin{pmatrix}\;2&\;1\\\!\!-1&\!\!-1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\;1&\;1\\\!\!-1&\!\!-2\end{pmatrix}\implies$$

$$P^{-1}MP=\begin{pmatrix}5&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\implies P^{-1}M^nP=\begin{pmatrix}5^n&0\\0&2^n\end{pmatrix}\implies M^n=P\begin{pmatrix}5^n&0\\0&2^n\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}\ldots$$

The second matrix is **not** diagonalizable (though you can try to triangle it...), but anyway you can try a direct approach and an inductive proof:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\;8&1\\\!\!-16&0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}\;8&1\\\!\!-16&0\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}\;48&\;8\\\!\!-128&\!\!-16\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}\;8&1\\\!\!-16&0\end{pmatrix}^3=\begin{pmatrix}\;256&\;48\\\!\!-768&\!\!-128\end{pmatrix}\ldots$$

BTW, the lower left entry **cannot** be correct, as the squared matrix proves.